# Caffe fails: relu_layer.cu: 29] check failed: error==cudaSuccess <9 vs 0> invalid configuration argument

Tags: caffe

When I run my Caffe implement, it fails as follows.

**...relu_layer.cu: 29] check failed: error==cudaSuccess <9 vs 0> invalid configuration argument**

It is noted that it does not fail in running other Caffe implements (eg. MNIST recognition).
My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce GT 620, with computaion ability 2.1, and on Windows 7.

If you come across the similar questions, please let me know, and give me some help.

Answer (score 1):

The driver is not the most updated. You can use http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Scan.aspx?lang=en-us 
to test your driver and update it.